# JAX-WS webservice not getting triggered in IBM WebSphere 8.5

Tags: jax-ws

We are facing one issue in webservice execution in IBM Websphere 8.5. We are having 3 IBM WAS 8.5 servers in 3 environments. We deployed JAX-WS Webservice in 2 environments and the Webservice is up and running. We are also able to generate WSDL. When we try to deploy the same EAR file which was deployed in the other 2 environments in 3rd environment , the application is installed successfully. But the Webservice is not up. We are not able to see WSDL file. Also, in admin console we are not able to see WebService properties section. The same we are able to see in admin console of the other 2 servers running in those 2 environments. Also we checked the logs and compared the logs from the working environment.
We are able to see the below log in the working environment
**[2/18/15 4:07:06:367 EST] 00000036 WASAxis2Exten I   WSWS7037I: The /PmdmMessageProcessor URL pattern was configured for the pwc.it.people.jw.service.endpoint.PmdmMessageProcessor servlet located in the PMDMJWServiceWeb.war web module**

But the same log we are unable to see in the 3rd environment where webservice is not working.

"**WASAxis2Exten**" is not getting triggered in the 3rd environment. Can you please help in this issue

Thanks and Regards
Kiran

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I've encountered the same problem. 
Deploying to the environment using the AdminConsole vs deploying using the AdminApp jython object.

Answer (score 0):

It helped for me to stop Websphere and delete the folders temp, wstemp and config/temp, then start again.